# shutil.copyfile PermissionError or FileNotFoundError Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I use the following code to copy a file (based on the zillion of examples online):

```
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

DATA_DIR = Path.cwd() / 'sourceFolder'
files = os.listdir(DATA_DIR)
shutil.copyfile(os.path.join('sourceFolder', files[0]), '/destFolder')
```

I receive this error (I do have all the necessary permissions on both the directory and file):

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/destFolder'

While, if I use this code (based on the other zillion of examples):

```
DATA_DIR = Path.cwd() / 'sourceFolder'
files = os.listdir(DATA_DIR)
des = os.path.join('/destFolder', files[0])
shutil.copyfile(os.path.join('sourceFolder', files[0]), des)
```

I receive the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/destFolder/nameOfFile

**ANSWER to Initial Question:**

I was finally able to make it work, adding the following lines of code:

```
dst = Path.cwd() / 'destFolder/nameOfFile'
shutil.copyfile(os.path.join('sourceFolder', files[0]), dst)
```

Thanks, J.

Comment: Does `/destFolder` exist?

Comment: if you are using linux, check permissions of destination folder, and also make sure it really exists.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes, the directory does exist and yes, I am on Linux and I have all the proper rights to the Directory in question, as mentioned in the description of the problem (Permissions are the following: drwxrwxr-x while I am the owner of the directory).

Comment: I have modified the initial post with the answer, adding two additional lines of code, as explained. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with all the comments already given above.  You probably want to add to your code:

```
import os
if not os.path.exists('/destFolder'):
   print("Creating destination folder");
   os.makedirs('/destFolder')
```